# Save As/Export as normal PDF (not Photoshop PDF) in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, pdf, export, save

I just want a normal PDF, as I will not edit the PDF, but rather go back to the PSD. Is there an option for saving as/exporting as just a normal PDF? If not, what settings do you change in the Photoshop PDF customization box, before exporting?

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

There is no "normal" PDF, just save it as a Photoshop PDF, because...**PDF is PDF**.

Sure, some programs may have differing export menus, but the essential options are the same, as Rafael mentioned below.  Settings are subjective to the creator and dependent upon the intended use of the PDF.

You say you want to email it? Adjust your image compression settings until you get an acceptable file size for viewing on the web. Use the downsampling options, until you find an acceptable value that yields satisfactory quality and file size.

**I'll usually use JPEG (lossy) @ 144dpi and find that yields good results for web use.**

Since you can't embed a PDF in an email's body, you will need to link to it anyway.

I typically try to keep my interactive PDFs < 2 mb, but sometimes more, because mine often include large images.

Comment: No, PDF is not just PDF. Photoshop PDF has a lot more things than a simple PDF (see https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/saving-pdf-files.html). For email especially, the least extra options, due to needing a smaller file size, is important.

Comment: Yes, PDF is jut PDF... Oh, but there are many flavors of PDF. But that are the intrinsec options of a PDF: version, color mode, transparencies, compatibility, resolution, embedded fonts etc. All thoose are the options of all PDFs.

Comment: @samseva I tried to leave a comment, but it was too long, so I'm adding it as an edit to my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can also export it as PNG or JPEG. 
And then right click on your picture. Then Print (On windows) and instead of choosing your printer choose save as PDF.

This will create a picture PDF much lower size than the photoshop PDF and impossible to reuse.

Comment: Hi Alex, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. If you want to know more about the site, please see the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and [help] or ping one of us in the [chat] once your reputation is sufficient (20). Keep contributing and enjoy the site!